# Jest testing a class in window

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm super lost how to do this.

We've got a class in window for Loqate called `window.pca.Addresses`

Then in our code we run this snippet of code in a react method:

```
const shippingControl = new pca.Address(shippingFields, { key: process.env.LOQATE_API_KEY });
window.setTimeout(() => {
  shippingControl.load();
}, 3000);
```

My question is how do I write a jest test to mock the Address class in the window and then also add the load() method so we can test if it has been fired or not.

I've tried to spyOn the window object as both global and window as well as mocking it with jest.mock() which also hasn't worked.

I'm wondering if anyone else can guide me on how to do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add `beforeEach` to your test something like that:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, "pca", {
      value: {
        Addresses: { load: jest.fn(() => null) }    
      },
      writable: true
    });
  });
```

You can test if it has been fired like this:

```
expect(window.pca.Addresses.load).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm getting an error saying that it hasn't been called. I'm wondering if it is due to the setTimeOut. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Ah what about if you want load to be inside Address? So pca.Address.load?

Comment: You need to add one more nested level, I changed my response!

Comment: hmm I tried that then I get this error: TypeError: pca.Address is not a constructor. So I tried to somehow mock Addresses so it had a constructor